# IOS Sprite Kit Images Across Devices

Tags: sprite-kit, retina-display, iphone-6-plus

So here is my issue:

I want to fully utilize Retina displays, as well as support as many devices as possible.

I'm trying to load in a background image that will fully fill the screen on every device. I had the artist create images at 2730x1536 which is ~ a 16x9 aspect ratio and had him take into account that I will have to crop for the ipad at 4:3.

From what I have read, a @3x image needs to be 2208x1242 then the iphone 6+'s retina display should scale it down to 1920x1080 physical pixels, making the image look sharp and fully fill my Landscape iphone 6+ screen.

I'm putting the Image in my scene as a SKSpriteNode. What size do I need to set my @3x (2208x1242) image to utilize retina without zooming the image?

Here is an example:

```
// Place a high res background image that perfectly fills my Landscape 6+ screen    
var image = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexutre(imageNamed: "background"), color: SKColor.clearColor(), size: CGSize(width: ????, height: ????))
```

What do I need to set my Height and width of a 2208x1242 image and scaleMode to perfectly fill a @3x iphone 6+ retina display screen if I'm locking the game in portrait?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also wasn't able to find any definitive documentation on this subject. If anyone knows of any, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In normal mode (non-zoom) the portrait iPhone 6+ display is 414x736 points. Your UIImageView should just be set to full screen using constraints to the edges of the superview. Like you said, you want to provide a 3x image of size 1242x2208 which then gets downsampled to 1920x1080. I'd suggest setting your scale mode to 'Center' so that the edges just get cropped on smaller resolutions. This [guide](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) may help you understand it more.

Comment: So my biggest question is how do I determine for sure that the 3x size is the one being used? If I have two images with the \@2x suffix and @3x suffix, how does the app decide to use the \@3x? and does this tag only mean something within xcassets? Thanks For the Answer!

Comment: There's a simple way to know "for sure" which size is being used - create a test image that has a "1" in the 1x version, a "2" in the 2x version etc. You'll see it use the 1x version on non-retina devices, the 2x version on retina devices, and the 3x version on iPhone6+. Individual images should be named with the @1x suffix, but you don't need to do that if you're using an asset catalog - just drag your images into the appropriate slots.